# Joomla showing IP instead of domain name

Tags: iis, server

I am hosting my own website on a Proliant Rack server using Internet Information Services. I have configured everything; port forwards, IIS, and also my Content Management System, Joomla. I have also registered a domain, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) (not the real domain obviously) with godaddy. I have also gone into proliant iLO and I have set the server FQDN to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). Finally, I forwarded the domain in godaddy to my public ip. However, when I enter in the URL ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) into a browser (outside of my network), it simply shows my IP address. My host file is as follows:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost 
127.0.0.1 example.com
127.0.0.1 www.example.com
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The serverfault sister site of SO is there to support administering server and network infrastructure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a site and bind its host name to your domain. Otherwise, IIS doesn't know what the domain point to.

[image]